# Dendrogram: control label position and formatting

Tags: output-formatting, cluster-analysis

How can I control the label position and formatting using `Dendrogram`?  I am looking for a way which is also easy to use when passing a clustering tree as input (instead of unclustered data).

This example is from the documentation:

```
Dendrogram[{Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Boston", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}], 
  Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", 
    "UnitedStates"}]}, Left]
```

The formatting is not ideal and definitely not suitable for publication figures:

[image]

`DendrogramPlot` from the HierarchicalClustering package uses left-alignment (or top-alignment) by default, which is better:

```
DendrogramPlot[{Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Boston", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}], 
  Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]}, 
 DistanceFunction -> QuantityMagnitude@*GeoDistance, 
 LeafLabels -> (# &), Orientation -> Left]
```

[image]

It also has the `LeafLabels` option, which makes it easier to control labelling independently of what data is passed into the function.

So this is easy to obtain too:

```
DendrogramPlot[{Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
  Entity["City", {"Boston", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}], 
  Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]}, 
 DistanceFunction -> QuantityMagnitude@*GeoDistance, 
 LeafLabels -> (Rotate[#, Pi/2] &)]
```

[image]

What if I'm stuck with `Dendrogram` and a pre-computed clustering tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possibilities. The first example is being adversely affected by the length of the labels. This can be fixed in a round-about manner by altering the `DistanceFunction`, e.g.

```
entities = {Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Sydney", "NewSouthWales", "Australia"}], 
 Entity["City", {"Boston", "Massachusetts", "UnitedStates"}], 
 Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}]};
Dendrogram[entities, Left, DistanceFunction -> (GeoDistance[##]^(1/3) &)]
```

[image]

which does well even when the image size is very small. Additionally, it is straightforward to generate the rotated text shown in your third example by using the

```
{data -> label ...}
```

form for the data, e.g.

```
data = (# -> Rotate[Style[CommonName@#, FontSize -> 14], Pi/2]) & /@ entities;
Dendrogram[entities]
```

[image]

But, that still makes the lines look ragged. This can be resolved by modifying the underlying graphics object:

```
Dendrogram[..., Left] /. Inset[g_, p_] :> Inset[g, p, Scaled[{0, 0.5}]]
Dendrogram[..., Right] /. Inset[g_, p_] :> Inset[g, p, Scaled[{1, 0.5}]]
Dendrogram[..., Top|Bottom] /. Inset[g_, p_] :> Inset[g, p, Scaled[{0.5, 1}]]
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The `Top|Bottom` is just for illustration, not real syntax, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs as in either `Top` (default) or `Bottom`. I didn't want to write it out twice. :)

Comment: If I have a clustering tree, the only way to rotate labels is to change them within the tree, right?  Example:  `tree = ClusteringTree[RandomReal[1, 10]];`, then `Dendrogram[
 SetProperty[tree, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Normal[Rotate[#, Pi/2] & /@ 
     Association@PropertyValue[tree, VertexLabels]]]]`.  The tree also has a `"LeafLabels"` graph property, but I don't know if I can count on it being there in future versions as it is not documented.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. However, you can do that when you create the `ClusteringTree` as it accepts the `{data -> label ..}` forms like `Dendrogram`.

Comment: [Actually, I am creating it manually, not with `ClusteringTree`.](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/commit/bc0e63004750d471aed6c13dbffc329deb52f014)  What I was originally looking for is a general structured representation of the dendrogram/clustering.  I thought Dendrogram didn't have this, but it turns out that it does: it is exactly the clustering tree, with a key property being the `VertexWeight`s.  This is all nice, but manipulating this tree is not as easy as manipulating `Cluster` expressions in the HierarchicalClustering package.

Comment: I think a much better and clearer separation of presentation and computation is needed.  Functions to do the clustering and return a hierarchy.  Functions for manipulating this hierarchy.  Then functions for plotting it.  I'll write to support eventually, but not right now. It takes time to make a good argument.  Also, both `FindClusters` and `FindGraphCommunities` should really really be able to create these hierarchies (independently of plotting) when the method supports it.  (They support many methods, not all hierarchical.)